# .save puts NULL in id field in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Here's the model file:

```
class ProfileTag < ActiveRecord::Base     
  def self.create_or_update(options = {})
    id = options.delete(:id)
    record = find_by_id(id) || new
    record.id = id
    record.attributes = options
    puts "record.profile_id is"
    puts record.profile_id

    record.save!

    record
  end
end
```

This gives me the correct print out in my log. But it also says that there's a call to UPDATE that sets `profile_id` to `NULL`. Here's some of the output in the log file:

```
Processing ProfilesController#update (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-05-28 18:20:54) [PUT]
Parameters: {"commit"=>"Save", "profile"=>{"id"=>"2", "password_confirmation"=>"", "username"=>"user2", "first_name"=>"user2_first", "password"=>"", "last_name"=>"user2_last"}, "authenticity_token"=>"...", "tag"=>"1", "id"=>"2"}
  ?[4;36;1mProfileTag Create (0.0ms)?[0m   ?[0;1mINSERT INTO `profile_tags` 
(`reputation_value`, `updated_at`, `tag_id`, `id`, `profile_id`, `created_at`) VALUES(0, '2010-05-29 01:20:54', 1, NULL, 4, '2010-05-29 01:20:54')?[0m
  ?[4;35;1mSQL (2.0ms)?[0m   ?[0mCOMMIT?[0m
  ?[4;36;1mSQL (0.0ms)?[0m   ?[0;1mBEGIN?[0m
  ?[4;35;1mSQL (0.0ms)?[0m   ?[0mCOMMIT?[0m
  ?[4;36;1mProfileTag Load (0.0ms)?[0m   ?[0;1mSELECT * FROM `profile_tags` WHERE (`profile_tags`.profile_id = 4) ?[0m
  ?[4;35;1mSQL (1.0ms)?[0m   ?[0mBEGIN?[0m
  ?[4;36;1mProfileTag Update (0.0ms)?[0m   ?[0;1mUPDATE `profile_tags` SET profile_id = NULL WHERE (profile_id = 4 AND id IN (35)) ?[0m
```

I'm not sure I understand why the `INSERT` puts the value into `profile_id` properly, but then it sets it to `NULL` on an `UPDATE`.

[Edit]
In ProfileController:

```
def update
  #...stuff. Set tags array.
  save_tags(tags) #These tags are correct. Verified by printouts before and after this call.
  respond_to do |format|
    if @profile.update_attributes(params[:profile])
      flash[:notice] = 'Profile was successfully updated.'
      #format.html { redirect_to(@profile) }
      format.html { redirect_to :action=>'show' }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "edit" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @profile.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def save_tags(tags)
  profile = find_profile #finds the correct profile. And I confirm that it exists with a printout
  tags.each do |t|
    ProfileTags.create_or_update(:profile_id => profile.profile_id, :tag_id => t.id)
  end
end
```

If you need more specifics, please let me know. I'm thinking that the `save` functionality does many things other than `INSERT`s into the database, but I don't know what I need to specify so that it will properly set `profile_id`.

Comment: don't you have callbacks doing that update?

Comment: I'm new to RoR. I didn't know what callbacks were until I saw your comment.
Are you saying that I wrote callbacks? I don't have any before_saves.
Also, there is no update action in the ProfileTagsController.
Sorry, I just don't understand your question.

Comment: Looking at the log, your code doesn't set `profile_id` to NULL during the save but rather `id` which would be a result of the line `id = options.delete(:id)`.  Have you taken a peek at your database to see what is actually happening?  Can you expand the log entry to include your custom lines?

Comment: Are you using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in your Profile model? Can look at the log file and show us the parameters passed to the update action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the line:

```
 ProfileTags.create_or_update(:profile_id => profile.profile_id, :tag_id => t.id)
```

I believe you want to pass `profile.id`, and not `profile.profile_id` (which is probably null).

Answer (score 0):

save! itself should't do this.

Maybe your problem is the name of the method. ActiveRecord::Base already have a method named create_or_update (see http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L2913) which is called by save! - maybe replacing it causes this weird problem.

Try changing the name of your method to something else, it might help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Slobodan, but it didn't work. I still get the UPDATE that sets the profile_id to NULL.

Comment: Can you post the code from your controller where you call create_or_update?

Comment: I would presume that you have something like has_many :profile_tags in your Profile model. If so then your problem might be @profile.update_attributes(params[:profile]) which saves the profile from memory which doesn't have any tags (so it sets it to null). Try commenting out save_tags call in controller and see in your log if there's still UPDATE query - if it's still there then update_attributes is to "blame".

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing the id attribute to the create_or_update method in the first place, so you don't need to call it, just call create instead, like so:

```
def save_tags(tags)
  profile = find_profile #finds the correct profile. And I confirm that it exists with a printout
  tags.each do |t|
    ProfileTag.create(:profile_id => profile.profile_id, :tag_id => t.id)
  end
end
```